# Promise function behaves differently in different scope

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, mongoskin, bluebird

I wrote a simple query function using promise and mongoskin and I want to test the query on the fly based on the use input.

The problem is the function **getUser** behaves differently in different context. 
Any ideas on why this is happening?

Here is my code:

PS: I have already **promisified** the mongoskin module

PS2: The callback **success**, **fail** are just printing out the errors by console.log()...

PS3: I use the **bluebird** promise & full code is updated

```
Database = function() {}
Database.prototype = (function() {
  /* private fields */
  var Promise = require('bluebird');
  var Mongo = require('mongoskin');
  var db = Mongo.db('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoapp');
  db.bind('user');

  /* promisify */
  Promise.promisifyAll(Mongo);

  return {
    constructor: Database,

    /* query function */
    getUser: function(chs) {
          return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              var re = { $regex: '^'+chs, $options: 'i' };
              db.user.find( { username : re } )
                     .toArrayAsync()
                     .then(resolve, reject);

          });
    }
  }
}());

/* use */
var db = new Database();
var success = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log('succeeded');
}

var fail = function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('fail');
}
// output: correct query result
db.getUser('blah').then(success, fail);

var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(cmd) {
   console.log('querying ' + cmd);
   // output: [TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'toArrayAsync']
   db.getUser('blah').then(success, fail);
});
```

Comment: Show us what promise library you are using and how you "promisified mongoskin"

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling the same `db.getUser` function? Show us the whole code.

Comment: I am using bluebird. Code updated.

Comment: Hm, this is really odd that it works the first time…

Comment: PLEASE don't use `return new Promise(function(..){ somePromiseReturning().then(resolve,reject);})` that's a known anti pattern. Simply do `return somePromiseReturning()` exact same result.

Comment: As for the bug - if I had to guess it's promisification not working correctly - is it possible that the cursor object gets reconstructed? Lemme have a look at mongoskin

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You mean that there is a static "current cursor" that gets promisified on the `Mongo` object?

Comment: I meant that there should be a single prototype, but maybe in this strange case there isn't. `Promise.promisifyAll` walks the prototype chain.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this? I really cannot figure this out.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot comprehend the issue. Judging from your code, the first `db.user.find(…)` Cursor that you created was promisified correctly, but the second was not. Can you try to reproduce the error with a simpler setup that allows some reasoning (like: "all but the first attempts fail.")? Or could you please debug to check whether the two Cursor objects do have the same prototype? (store the results of `Object.getPrototype(…)` and compare them)